# rsync of sparse qemu image increases disk size

Tags: rsync, qemu, xfs, sparse-files

I have a sparse raw qemu image that I want to transfer to another server. `qemu-img info` gives me:

```
image: sparse.img
file format: raw
virtual size: 50G
disk size: 16G
```

I transfer it with:

```
rsync -azhP --sparse origin:/path/to/img/sparse.img .
```

Now, on the destination server I have:

```
image: sparse.img
file format: raw
virtual size: 50G
disk size: 40G
```

However, after running `virt-sparsify` again on the copied image, I get this:

```
image: sparse.img
file format: raw
virtual size: 50G
disk size: 16G
```

Both servers are running CentOS 7.2 on a XFS filesystem. So what happened?

#### Update:

After some more research, I found several posts indicating that rsync doesn't handle sparse files well, and that it's better to use a different tool, [such as tar](http://jfargen.blog.usf.edu/2012/10/11/how-to-copy-sparse-files-faster/), to transfer sparse files.

You could follow up the `tar` transfer with `rsync --inplace`, to make sure the file was transferred wtihout errors, as explained [here](https://gergap.wordpress.com/2013/08/10/rsync-and-sparse-files/).

Another [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120091/how-can-i-speed-up-operations-on-sparse-files-with-tar-gzip-rsync) that was proposed was creating an empty sparse file of the same size on the destination, and then using `rsync --inplace` to transfer the actual data.

I didn't write this as a solution, because it doesn't really explain why `rsync --sparse` is behaving this way.

Comment: Did you transfer it a first time without `--sparse` and then repeat the process to try and turn the full file into a sparse one?

Comment: No. Just one transfer.

Comment: That's certainly not expected behaviour. Your command looks good to me. What version of `rsync` (use `rsync --version`)

Comment: The `rsync` version is `3.0.9 protocol version 30`. I have noticed a few instances where Redhat has made strange alterations to the default behavior of a package, but I think that's unlikely in this case.

Comment: If xfs is continually pre-allocating space at eof as the file grows,
perhaps you can try asking rsync to start with a sparse file of the right
size with `rsync --preallocate`

Comment: What is the size on disk? Please provide du output

Comment: @meuh Unfortunately, the version of rsync I'm using doesn't support the `--preallocate` flag.

Comment: @Dani_I The output for all images is the same as with `qemu-img info`.

Answer (score 3):

I bet this is due to FS disparities between the source and the destination.

Let me elaborate with an example. Sparse files are files whose empty blocks (i.e. full of 0) are not allocated on the disk. The smaller the block size on the FS, the likelier such a block can be found. So, your issue may be due to a block size being bigger on the destination than on the source.

There may be other XFS parameters that I don't know.

See also [this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/406069/why-are-my-xfs-filesystems-suddenly-consuming-more-space-and-full-of-sparse-file)

Comment: I get the same result when copying the image locally from one partition to another, both XFS. Could this still apply in that situation? It seems that the block size would have to be the same for partitions on the same HDD. Also, running `virt-sparsify` again restores the smaller disk size.

Comment: +1 for the ServerFault reference. The OP offered the `rsync --sparse` command in their question

Comment: @roaima Thx. My question to orodbhen is about the local copy that they mention in an earlier comment.

Comment: @orodbhen [same comment as earlier, I forgot to ping you] That's really strange. How do you copy your image locally? With `cp` or `rsync`? Can you try `cp --sparse=always`?

Comment: @xhienne I used the exact same `rsync` command, minus the `-z` option. It's not over the network, so no compression needed.

Comment: @orodbhen Try with `cp --sparse=always` instead and see if something changes. If not it may be an XFS issue, else it may be a `rsync` issue.

Comment: Using `cp --sparse` is much faster than `rsync`, and the destination size is much closer to the original. From a `1.8GB` disk size, it created a `2.5GB` file. Even within the same filesystem, `rsync` is very inefficient.

Comment: @orodbhen The size is still different than the original. It shouldn't be. Does a subsequent `virt-sparsify` make the file even smaller? If so, I guess the problem is on the `xfs` side.

Comment: @xhienne Yes, the disk size is a little bigger. The virtual size never changes.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I have found that works best for me is to first run

```
virt-sparsify imagename
```

Takes some time.
That produces a smaller size image that reports the same size both in `ls -h`, `du -h` and `du -h --apparent-size`. But when you mount the image it reports the correct size (and grows as expected).

Then rsync that image.